# How can i read the results from KEEL after generate Output zip file?

Tags: data-mining

KEEL (Knowledge Extraction based on Evolutionary Learning)
How can i read the results from KEEL after generate Output zip file ?
I download KEEL and import my Data then add the algorithm .
the execute for this application generate the zip file.
How can i read the results from KEEL after generate Output zip file ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for "results folder" inside the .zip after you run RunKeel.jar on Scripts folder, edit files with a text editor and find for the values you want. Better if you use a Vis-Clas-General (Algorithm, for show multiple result) when realize the experiment design .